# Re-use of concurrently running tasks

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Ok, I've changed the question itself because I think it was not very clear.

```
public void Start()
{
    IEnumerable<Action> originalTasks = new Action[] { () => LongRunningMethod(), () => LongRunningMethod2() };

    Parallel.ForEach(originalTasks, task =>
    {
        task.Invoke();
    });
}

public void LongRunningMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Long running method executed.");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}

public void LongRunningMethod2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Long running method 2 executed.");
}
```

You'll see that I have 2 methods 'LongRunningMethod()' and 'LongRunningMethod2()'.
The 'LongRunningMethod' has a sleep of 10 seconds.

Now here's what I would like to achieve.

The parellel foreach should be entered (which is the case), and as soon as I'm in the parallel loop a timer of 5 seconds will start. When those 5 seconds are finished, I want to re-run the parallel loop (I know in this case it's not good because I'm starting a thread while another one is still running.

In the production environment, every task will have a variable called "isRunning" that I will use to see if I can re-run it or not.

I hope that someone can provide me some help with this issue.

Kind regards,

Comment: What is your question ?:)

Comment: There is no guarantee that `Parallel.ForEach` runs in parallel.

Comment: I know, but at least a task that takes 5 hours doesn't block all the other stuff.

Comment: Have you looked at `Task.WaitAll()`? If yes, why are you not using that instead?

Comment: It's my first threaded thing, so I'm quite unsure on how to process

Comment: Can it be a solution to make the tasks to the call async ?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is blocking, so I think what you are after will require controlling each individual `Task` object yourself.

Comment: Okay, I think what you're really looking for is `Task.WhenAny()`. This method blocks until one of many tasks has completed, passing the completed tasks on to a continuation method. This continuation is where you'd handle rescheduling the completed task.

Comment: Would you mind providing a little example as I'm quite new to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can control the flow of your program using a custom state object. This state object would be used in continuation methods to determine which tasks are finished and should be rescheduled.

Sample:

```
class TaskState
{
    public int OneSecondTaskId { get; set; }
    public int TenSecondTaskId { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldRescheduleOneSecondTask { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldRescheduleTenSecondsTask { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task oneSecondTask = null;
        Task tenSecondTask = null;
        var state = new TaskState()
                        {
                            ShouldRescheduleOneSecondTask = true,
                            ShouldRescheduleTenSecondsTask = true
                        };

        while (true)
        {

            if (state.ShouldRescheduleOneSecondTask)
            {
                oneSecondTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Slept 1 second");
                    });
                state.OneSecondTaskId = oneSecondTask.Id;
                state.ShouldRescheduleOneSecondTask = false;
            }

            if (state.ShouldRescheduleTenSecondsTask)
            {
                tenSecondTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Slept 10 seconds");
                    });
                state.TenSecondTaskId = tenSecondTask.Id;
                state.ShouldRescheduleTenSecondsTask = false;
            }

            var handleTaskCompletionTask = Task.WhenAny(oneSecondTask, tenSecondTask).ContinueWith(
                (completedTask, o) =>
                {
                    var taskState = (TaskState)o;

                    var taskId = completedTask.Result.Id;

                    if (taskId == taskState.OneSecondTaskId)
                    {
                        taskState.ShouldRescheduleOneSecondTask = true;
                    }

                    if (taskId == taskState.TenSecondTaskId)
                    {
                        taskState.ShouldRescheduleTenSecondsTask = true;
                    }
                }, state);

            handleTaskCompletionTask.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 10 seconds
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 10 seconds
> Slept 1 second
> Slept 1 second
> ...
> ```

Comment: Thanks, it's starting to make sense, but in your example, you use "ContinueWith" and you specify a specific task. But my tasks are different, so which Task should I place in the ContinueWith method than?

Comment: If the problem is that not all tasks return `void` the way they would in my example, then you can explicitly specify the return type using the `.ContinueWith<TResult>()` overload.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Can you have a look at my post. I've changed it to the code I have right now. It would be great if you can adapt my code to be fully functional because I'm really lost in the forest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I read your updated question. Polling the task's status when you can just wait for it to complete instead is a weird way of doing things. Are you sure you want to use a timer for this?

Comment: I use parallel. For each for the moment. Where do you see my timer?

Comment: `as soon as I'm in the parallel loop a timer of 5 seconds will start`. For what purpose?

Comment: Well. All the tasks run in parallel. And after 5 seconds (or when one task in the loop is conpleted) I want to execute the tasks in the loop again. I'll hope it is clear now. If not. Just tell

Comment: Two questions. Suppose that you've started 20 tasks. (question 1) When 5 seconds elapse, what happens to all 20 tasks? (question 2) When 1 task out of 20 completes, what happens to that task? What happens to the other 19 tasks?

Comment: Let's get rid of the 5 seconds to make things clear. So, when a task out of the 20 completes, I want to re-run all the 20 tasks (the tasks that are still running should not be executed again). Basicly, I want the following: I have 20 tasks, they should be executed parallel, and when 1 task completes, I want to wait for a couple of seconds, minutes, hours and then restart the completed task. I hope it's more understandable right now.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why you're against individually handling task completion for each task.

Comment: I'm not against that, if I can have a solution by managing the tasks myself, that's not a problem at all. So if you have any ideas, just fire them to me. I just want to run x tasks in parallel, and as soon as 1 single task has finished, re-execute the x tasks (without cancelling the previous runs).

Comment: That's the thing though. When you handle each task individually, you typically don't touch the other tasks unless you have a very good reason to do so. I think you may have a good reason, but I'm not seeing it clearly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50843/discussion-between-kevin-de-coninck-and-steven-liekens)

Comment: So, I've explained the whole story on the chat. You are welcome :-)
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50843/discussion-between-kevin-de-coninck-and-steven-liekens

Answer (score 1):

So first off, to have some code run after each tasks ends and do some further processing on that task you want to call `ContinueWith` on each of those tasks.

To do something 5 minutes after they have all started you can use `Task.Delay`.

```
IEnumerable<Task> originalTasks = CreateTasks();

var continuations = originalTasks.Select(task => 
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        DoStuffWithTask(t);
    }))
    .ToList();

Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
    .ContinueWith(t => CheckOnTasks());
```